# CosmosDB storing IP Address ranges and searching by an IP

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am investigating storing IP ranges in cosmosDB where for example I have millions of entries including ranges like  65.55.243.0  to  65.55.243.255  linked with other data that does not matter. Can anyone suggest on how to store this in cosmos assuming that I will be searching by an IP address 100% of the time to get to the range that it belongs to? In SQL I have done this but I am wondering if this can be done efficiently in CosmosDB. Thanks! #cosmosdb

Comment: It would help to provide an example of your data to understand what it might look like.

Comment: The problem is not as simple. Consider the format below where you have millions of IP ranges stored in this format. What is your primary key in this case? The primary query that needs to be supported here is querying by an IP address and figuring out which range it belongs to! 
network_start_ip,  network_last_ip,  geoname_id registered_country_geoname_id ...
52.144.102.128 52.144.102.255 4710129 6252001  0 
52.144.103.0        52.144.103.255 4694459 6252001  0
...
....

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how the data looks, I think you should be able to leverage Cosmos to get efficient queries using several aspects. It's worth reading up on [how Cosmos does indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview), which includes automatic range indexes on strings like IP addresses. This means you can efficiently query those values using native [string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-string-functions) including STARTSWITH or CONTAINS.

Beyond the queries themselves, how you structure the data impacts the performance. Most important is to select a [partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview) to segment the data. In your case, using the IP address as the basis of the partition key sounds like a good option, assuming you'll know which IP and therefore which partition to query in advance. The rule of thumb is to design the data such that you never have cross-partition queries.

Beyond that, you could add variants of the address data in additional properties to query against, like { subnet: 65.55.243.0/24 }. Knowing the subnet in that case allows you to efficiently query for all records by exact match, which seems generally the most efficient query type.

In general, I've found:

- Simplest queries perform best, more complex means more cost
- Design data shape to facilitate simple queries
- Choose a partition key that is derived from information available at query time to always target single partition

Comment: The problem is not as simple . Consider the following format
network_start_ip,  network_last_ip,  geoname_id registered_country_geoname_id ...
52.144.102.128 52.144.102.255 4710129 6252001  0 
52.144.103.0        52.144.103.255 4694459 6252001  0

Comment: If the query is for 52.144.102.129, you could find by query in range between start and end, like "select * from c where  "52.144.102.129" >= c.network_start_ip AND  "52.144.102.129" <= c.network_last_ip. Another idea would be to store one record for every possible IP that is just the address and an ID for the network info for separate lookup. In either case I would try to partition by the address or some prefix of it.